# React-Tooltip space from the left of Icon

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I am trying to do space of react tooltip from the left side of the icon but I am not able to achieve my goal . I tried each and every `css` properties like `MarginLeft` or `position:absoulte; left:` but space is not generated could someone please help me how to achieve my goal

**Code**

```
 <i className="fa fa-download agencyDefualt" id="TooltipExample"></i>
 <Tooltip placement="right"
         isOpen={this.state.tooltipOpen}
         target="TooltipExample"
         toggle={this.toggle}>
            export all properties
 </Tooltip>
```

Comment: please add a codesanbox link

Answer (score 0):

So, `Tooltip` component has `placement` property which sets the direction the Tooltip is positioned towards. I think you need to change value from `right` to `left` and tooltip appear from the left side of the icon. Next values available for use:

- 'auto-start'
- 'auto'
- 'auto-end'
- 'top-start'
- 'top'
- 'top-end'
- 'right-start'
- 'right'
- 'right-end'
- 'bottom-end'
- 'bottom'
- 'bottom-start'
- 'left-end'
- 'left'
- 'left-start'

More information about `Tooltip` component you can find by next link: [Tooltip](https://react-bootstrap.netlify.com/components/overlays/#tooltip-props)

Example with part of your code:

```
<i className="fa fa-download agencyDefualt" id="TooltipExample"></i>
 <Tooltip placement="left"
         isOpen={this.state.tooltipOpen}
         target="TooltipExample"
         toggle={this.toggle}>
            export all properties
 </Tooltip>
```

Just was changed attribute to `placement="left"`